# How to display content in two column three row checkerboard in a mobile first responsive grid

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am a beginner, and I am having trouble recreating my mockup in CSS. One issue is the second section of my homepage (benefits).  I wanted a two column checkerboard layout alternating white and cardboard backgrounds.  I'm not sure if the answer is to change the media queries or include more subclasses.  I'm generally lost on this.  [Here is my mockup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9cmb5sg4hqfu6bj/Home%20Page.jpg?dl=0).  Thank you in advance.

Did I mention that you have to speak to me as if I am 5 years old?

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #1F1309;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

header .logo {
  float: left;
}

header nav {
  padding: 1em 0;
}

header nav ul {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

header nav ul>li.btn-outline {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

header nav ul>li.btn-outline:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

header nav ul>li>a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul>li.btn-outline:hover>a {
  color: #845F5A;
}

header .headline {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
}

header .headline h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 95px 0 0;
}

header .headline p {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
}

header,
footer,
section {
  overflow: auto;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Crimson Text", Helvetica, Arial, serif;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-weight: 100;
}


/* GRID */

.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.one-half,
.one-third,
.one-fourth {
  width: 96%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin: 0 2% 20px;
}


/*IMAGES*/

.hero {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url("images/brainstorm.png");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.overlay:hover:before {
  display: block;
}

.black:before {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: .35;
}

.brown:before {
  background-color: #7E6233;
}

.hero * {
  position: relative;
  /* hack */
}


/* BUTTONS */

.btn {
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #F9461C;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 2px rgba(71, 19, 7, 0.90);
  ;
}

.container-second-hero {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 287px;
  background-image: url("images/Guy-on-grass.png");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.benefits {
  background-image: url("images/cardboard.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #1F1309;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.benefits ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.benefits i {
  color: #1F1309;
  font-size: 144px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  height: 336px;
  width: 100%;
}

.benefits h2 {
  color: #1F1309;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.benefits p {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.additional-features {
  background-image: url("images/cardboard.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.additional-features h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.additional-features h3 {
  font-family: "Crimson Text", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #1F1309;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.additional-features ul {
  color: #1F1309;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  list-style: none;
}


/* PRICING */

.pricing {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 4em 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4em 0;
}

.pricing h2,
.pricing h3,
.pricing h4,
.pricing p {
  color: #1F1309;
  line-height: 0.5em;
}

.pricing ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0;
}

.pricing ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pricing .container p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.box {
  padding: 0 0 15px;
  background: rgba(124, 49, 70, 0.18);
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  min-height: 439px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box.middle {
  border: 1px solid rgba(31, 19, 8, 0.55);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 1px rgba(46, 60, 65, 0.52);
  background: #FFFFFF;
  min-height: 485px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 110%;
}

.box h3 {
  font-family: "Crimson Text", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.box h4 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 40px 0 10px;
  color: #1F1309;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.box h4 span {
  font-size: 32px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.box h4 span.month {
  font-family: "Crimson Text", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #1F1309;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box ul li {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.box .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
}

.small {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FEFEFE;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}


/* TESTIMONIALS */

.testimonials {
  padding: 4em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonials h2 {
  color: #1F1309;
}

.testimonials ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.testimonials blockquote {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  background: #1F1309;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.testimonials blockquote:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 13%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-top-color: #1F1309;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.testimonials img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
}

.testimonials p.name {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.testimonials .second,
.fourth {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}


/* FOOTER */

footer {
  background-color: #34495E;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #3498DB 0%, #3498DB 50%, #34495E 50%, #34495E 100%);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

footer p,
footer nav ul {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}

footer nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

footer nav ul li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer .right-footer-block {
  background-color: transparent;
}

footer .logo {
  padding: 2.35em 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  footer {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3498DB 0%, #3498DB 33.33337%, #34495E 33.33337%, #34495E 100%);
    height: 100px;
  }
  footer p,
  footer nav ul {
    padding: 2em 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  footer .right-footer-block {
    background-color: #3498DB;
  }
  footer .logo {
    padding: 2em 0 2em 1.5em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
  .one-half {
    width: 46%;
  }
  .one-third {
    width: 32.64177%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .one-fourth {
    width: 21%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 4000px) {
  .container {
    width: 3800px;
  }
  html {
    font-size: 150% line-height: 150%
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UZ-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta charset="UTF-0">
  <title>Save, share, and collaborate | Blockbox</title>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Hero -->
    <header>
      <div class="hero overlay black">
        <nav class="container">
          <div class="one-half">
            <a href="index.html" class="site-white-logo"><img src="images/site-white-logo.png" alt="Blocbox" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="one-half">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="signin.html">Sign In</a></li>
              <li class="btn-outline"><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container headline">
          <h1 class="animated fadeIn">Save, share and collaborate.</h1>
          <p>blocbox lets you collect and sort information.<br/>Create simple notes, store images, and add links.</p>
          <a href="signup.html" class="btn">Start Your Free Trial!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main role="main">

      <!-- Benefits -->
      <section class="benefits">
        <ul class="container">
          <li class="one-half">
            <div class="top">
              <h2>Create notes</h2>
              <p>Using Markdown, you can create simple text-based documents to save and share. You can collaborate with others to write and edit content.</p>
            </div>

            <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
            <div class="bottom">
              <h2>Add Links</h2>
              <p>Forget bookmarking sites in your browser. With blocbox, you can add links, group them and view them from any computer.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="one-half">
            <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            <div class="middle">
              <h2>Save images</h2>
              <p>Are there images you find interesting enough to save? Now you have a way to organize and store those within blocbox.</p>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
        </ul>
      </section>

      <!-- Additional Features -->
      <section class="additional-features">
        <div class="container-second-hero">
          <h1>Access blocbox anywhere.</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="container">
          <li class="one-third">
            <h3>Collaborate</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Invite collaborators</li>
              <li>Chat in real time</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="one-third">
            <h3>Organize</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Tag items</li>
              <li>Search for items</li>
              <li>Create boxes</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="one-third">
            <h3>Do</h3>
            <ul>
              <i class="fa-calendar-check-o"></i>
              <li>Assign due dates</li>
              <i class="fa-clock-o"></i>
              <li>Set reminders</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <!-- Pricing -->
      <section class="pricing">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>How much does blocbox cost?</h2>
          <p>We have many options to fit your needs. It's free to try for 30 days*, and you can always change your plan once you signed up. <br/>Here are the different features of each plan:</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="container">
          <li class="one-third">
            <div class="box">
              <h3>Casual</h3>
              <h4>Free</h4>
              <ul>
                <li>Up to 5 boxes</li>
                <li>Up to 10 collaborators</li>
                <li><strong>2GB</strong> of storage</li>
              </ul>
              <a href="signup.html" class="btn">Start Your Free Trial!</a>
            </div>
            <li class="one-third">
              <div class="box middle">
                <h3>Professional</h3>
                <h4><span>$</span>5<span class="month">/month</span></h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>Unlimited boxes</li>
                  <li>Up to 20 collaborators</li>
                  <li><strong>5GB</strong> of storage</li>
                  <li>Real-time collaboration</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="signup.html" class="btn">Start Your Free Trial!</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="one-third">
              <div class="box">
                <h3>Expert</h3>
                <h4><span>$</span>10<span class="month">/month</span></h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>Unlimited boxes</li>
                  <li>Unlimited collaborators</li>
                  <li><strong>Unlimited</strong> storage</li>
                  <li>Real-time collaboration</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="signup.html" class="btn">Start Your Free Trial!</a>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </section>

      <!-- Testimonials -->
      <section class="testimonials">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Who uses blocbox?</h2>
          <p>blocbox has more than 100,000 satisfied users storing and collaborating<br/> with teams across the world. Here's what a few have to say:</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="container">
          <div class="first">
            <li class="one-fourth">
              <blockquote>"blocbox has made it easier to find and keep things I love. I can share with other designers on my team and create new categories with awesome stuff. And creating simple text documents couldn't be easier."
              </blockquote>
              <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/620606106142806016/_80ZF1Qd.jpg" alt="avatar">
              <p class="name"><strong>Abinav Thakuri</strong><br/>Freelance Designer, N. Dakota</p>
          </div>
          </li>
          <li class="one-fourth second">
            <div class="second">
              <blockquote>"blocbox has made it easier to find and keep things I love. I can share with other designers on my team and create new categories with awesome stuff. And creating simple text documents couldn't be easier."
              </blockquote>
              <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/620606106142806016/_80ZF1Qd.jpg" alt="avatar">
              <p class="name"><strong>Abinav Thakuri</strong><br/>Freelance Designer, N. Dakota</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="one-fourth third">
            <blockquote>"blocbox has made it easier to find and keep things I love. I can share with other designers on my team and create new categories with awesome stuff. And creating simple text documents couldn't be easier."
            </blockquote>
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/620606106142806016/_80ZF1Qd.jpg" alt="avatar">
            <p class="name"><strong>Abinav Thakuri</strong><br/>Freelance Designer, N. Dakota</p>
          </li>
          <li class="one-fourth fourth">
            <div class="fourth">
              <blockquote>"blocbox has made it easier to find and keep things I love. I can share with other designers on my team and create new categories with awesome stuff. And creating simple text documents couldn't be easier."
              </blockquote>
              <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/620606106142806016/_80ZF1Qd.jpg" alt="avatar">
              <p class="name"><strong>Abinav Thakuri</strong><br/>Freelance Designer, N. Dakota</p>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </section>

      <!-- Call to Action -->
      <section class="CTA">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Ready to give it a try?</h2>
          <p>We have many options to fit your needs. It's free to try for 30 days*, and you can always change your plan once you signed up.</p>
          <a href="signup.html" class="btn">Start Your Free Trial!</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
          <div class="container footer-nav-block">
            <div class="left-footer-block one-third">
              <p class="copyright-block">&copy; 2015. <strong>Blocbox</strong> - All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div>
            <nav class="link-block middle-footer-block one-third">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Terms</a></li> /
                <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li> /
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li> /
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li> /
                <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="right-footer-block one-third">
              <img class="logo" src="images/site-brown-logo.png" alt="Blocbox" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>

    </main>
  </body>

</html>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could reduce the complexity of your question by providing just the necessary css classes and html markup. Also, try out frameworks like bootstrap or material design and try to read through their docs regarding grid systems.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make it a table, and use CSS to set the background using some nth-child logic.

To center your text you can use flex boxes with a container inside of it, I just made it a div and marked it as display:inline-block; with some CSS.

Since I'm pretty sure your cardboard is an image, all you'd have to do is to replace the background-color:rgb(###,###,###); by a background-image element.

and you should be it.

```css
table.Container{
  width:100%;
}
table.Container td{
  display:inline-flex;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:2in;
  flex-direction:row;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:50%;
}
table.Container td > div{
  display:inline-block;
}
table.Container tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(odd),
table.Container tr:nth-child(even) > td:nth-child(even){
  background-color:rgb(219, 148, 50);
}
table.Container tr:nth-child(even) > td:nth-child(odd),
table.Container tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(even){
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="Container">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><div>your ontent here</div></td>
          <td><div>your ontent here</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div>your ontent here</div></td>
          <td><div>your ontent here</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div>your ontent here</div></td>
          <td><div>your ontent here</div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```